# Change text in AWS cognito login UI

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am working on customizing the cognito login UI using AWS.

In **App client settings** I have given like,

[image]

And the above inputs result in the following,

[image]

**Requirement:** Here I am in the need to change the text in sign In.

Like, `Continue with Google` **to** `Sign In with Google` .

I could only able to see changing of border, padding, margin to the input boxes but not able find out a way to change the text under **UI Customization**.

So what should I need to do to change the text of the above given button?

Comment: Not applicable to your question. But this may help others. If all you want is to display a short message on the login form create an image of your text and upload it as logo. This off course looks absolutely unprofessional and is not at all accessible for blind people, but it has served me well as a quick and dirty message board on internal login pages, where I don't care about looks.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately this is not possible va the Cognito UI.

The only only options provided are related to the styling of the interface, not the modification of the UI.

If you have explicit need to have certain text, you will need to create your own solution combined with the SDK/CLI for AWS cognito.

Comment: So, if you take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html it explains the workflow. You'll want to use the SDK to implement the functions. If you're new you might be able to use Amplify to help implement some of this: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js#sign-in